# Android application's initial activity is not the launcher designated activity when re-entering the app with the back button

Tags: android, android-activity, back, launch

I ran into a similar issue with the recent list in that there seem to a handful of conditions where an app will be completely destroyed but some other process will launch the app cold from  the last activity that was being used. Since my app has a state that is built up over several designated activities I need to prevent this (i.e. null refs from onCreate()).

Without checking for state is all my onCreate() functions is there a way to just prevent this?

Also, other than the launcher, recents, the back button from other apps - are there more conditions where another thing can launch my app if I have not giving manifest permission to launch it explicitly with an intent?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your launchMode in your manifest? This sounds like it could be solved with singleTop as your launchMode, if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: singleTop doesn't fix it. If any of my activities gets launched before my startup activity when starting the application then the system is in an invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you have initializations in activity B that rely on activity A having passed them in. If an intent launches activity B first, without it being active, or being launched by A first, your activity will crash.

Easiest solution I can come up with is make your activity A (I assume your main activity) the broadcast listener for all the intents you wish to handle, and based off the intent action, dispatch to the appropriate child activities (B, C, whatever). That way activity A does all your initialization, and you can still launch into the appropriate activity to handle the original intent you wanted to.

Alternatively. If you detect your children activities are in an invalid state, you could put initialization into a parent activity that all your activities extend from. That way you should be able to initialize properly if the activity is a fresh launch. I'm not really a fan of this, I prefer making sure my activities are dependency injected with appropriate data.

Comment: Your first paragraph is correct and di will eventually solve this (read - inherited legacy windows code ported to Android.) Do you know of a code example construction for your description in paragraph 2? I'd like to see an impl to judge if will meet the requirements.